# .htaccess link to a directory not under document root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to link a directory from my document root to a directory which is not under document root. Example structure (document root is www)
my_web/www/
my_web/www/images/custom/ <- there I want to place .htaccess
my_web/var/
my_web/var/uploads/images/ <- there it should point

So, for example when I access http://my.example.com/images/custom/foo.jpg, the server should respond with my_web/var/uploads/images/foo.jpg if it exists (of course it cannot be a 301 redirect).

Is this possible just through .htaccess? I know how to use mod_rewrite, but it seems that it cannot redirect to anything outside the document root folder.

I have only FTP access to the server, so I cannot set any file system symbolic links there. The only solution I see now is to create a simple PHP file under the images/custom folder, point .htaccess to it and retrieve the requested file from /var with it, but pure .htaccess solution would be more simple and elegant.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In htaccess (directory context), it's only possible to rewrite from a URL to a URL, not to a filesystem path. If that filesystem space is not reachable by an existing alias, and permitted to be served with a Directory block, you won't have any success.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll use another solution, probably the PHP script.